# C++ : Using an array in a nested class definition (OOP)

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, class

So I am trying to define a class and I am using another array of a different class to define it.

```
  //header file for Name.h
class Name {
    string last;
    string first;
}; 

 //header file for Depositor.h
    class Depositor {
        Name name;
        string ssn;}; 



//header file for Account.h 
    class Account {
        Depositor depositor;
        int acctnum;
        string type;
        double balance;
    };

//header file for Bank.h
#include "Account.h"
class Bank {
    Account account[]; //is this possible?
    int active_accts;
};
```

When I am writing the cpp file I am running into a lot of problems!

```
//example of mutator
void Bank::setLastname(string lastname)
{
    account.setLastname (lastname);
}
```

I didn't include the mutators and acessors that I wrote into the header file, but they are there and are public -- it won't compile.
Can you help? Is it even valid to use an array of a class in Bank.h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By declaring the value of the array in the header file and by adding a variable in the .cpp file you can solve all the problems and leave it as an array.

```
//header file
class Bank {
  Account account[100];
  int active_accts;
 public:
//mutator
void setLastname (string,int);
};

//the implementation file
void Bank::setLastname (string last, int index)
{
   account[index].setLastname(last);
}
```

this will solve all your problems

Answer (score 2):

> Is it even valid to use an array of a class in Bank.h?

Yes, but it has to have a fixed dimension, e.g.,

```
Account account[3];
```

A type always has a fixed size in C++, and since an array member variable forms part of the class's size, you need to specify how many elements are in the array.

If you don't know how many elements you are going to need, you can use a sequence container:

```
std::vector<Account> account;
```

Comment: Of course, a member array's size can be specified via a *non-type template parameter*. That's how [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/array.html) works.

Comment: @In:  Sure, but then it still becomes part of the type; the array underlying a `boost::array<T, 3>` has a dimension of 3:  it's known and fixed, and `boost::array<T, 3>` is a different type from `boost::array<T, 4>`.

Comment: Right. The OP would still have to provide the size of the array at some time during compile time.

Answer (score 1):

- `Account` is not a nested class of `Bank`. `Bank` has a *member* data instance of type `Account` array.
- You can have a primitive array member in a class, but you must specify the size of the array in the class definition: `Account account[42];`. The reason is that when you `#include` the class definition in another compilation unit, and then instantiate an instance of the class, the compiler needs to know what the size of that instance is.
- It would be a wise idea to use `std::vector<Account>` rather than a primitive array. `std::vector` doesn't require committing to a particular size at construction; it grows dynamically. How come a `std::vector` doesn't require a size in the class definition, while a primitive array does? A `std::vector` holds as member a *pointer* to the elements on the heap. So the compiler does know the size of a `std::vector`; it uses the size of the pointer rather than the count of the elements.

Comment: "I didn't include the mutators and acessors that I wrote into the header file, but they are there and are public"

Quote the OP, so that mutes your first and third point, as he is using mutators, and not accessing the variables directly.
Otherwise valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

`account` is an array of `Account`s, which means you would need to do something like `account[0].setLastname(lastname);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrays, consider using vectors.

```
#include <vector>

// ...

class Bank {
    std::vector<Account> accounts;
    int active_accts;
};
```

Comment: Yes, though active_accts was probably an attempt at managing the size, which vector handles for you, and it would then be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call `setLastname(lastname)` on the whole array. You need to call it on a specific instance of the Account class inside the array, like this: `account[0].setLastname(lastname);`

On another note, you really should be storing an array of **pointers** to Account objects.

Comment: as noted in other answers, a vector is actually a better solution. It allows for an expandable storage location. You still need pointer though.

Comment: Depending on how big the Account class is and how many there are, you could fill up the stack pretty easily. It's better to have an array of pointers to Account objects that are allocated on the heap instead of on the stack.